# OKTA authentication Request 400 Bad Request Header or Cookie Too Large

Tags: authentication, .net-core, model-view-controller, okta

I am facing this error while authenticating users in .net core mvc application using OKTA. It works fine but if I login using OKTA and come back to mvc application again after 2 hours and try to use mvc application, it gives the error Bad Request, Request Header or Cookie too large. Can anyone please suggest what could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late to answer this, I happened to encounter this issue too and what I did was

> Right Click on Browser > Inspect > Application > Cookies > Clear

Reason being is that there is too much cookies saved up, though this is a manual way to overcome it.

Another way is to expire the cookies by coding in your application